# How to convert C# nullable int to int

Tags: c#, nullable

How do I convert a nullable `int` to an `int`? Suppose I have 2 type of int as below:

```
int? v1;  
int v2;
```

I want to assign `v1`'s value to `v2`. `v2 = v1;` will cause an error. How do I convert `v1` to `v2`?

Comment: What is the desired behavior when `v1` is `null`?

Answer (score 777):

The other answers so far are all correct; I just wanted to add one more that's slightly cleaner:

```
v2 = v1 ?? default(int);
```

Any `Nullable<T>` is implicitly convertible to its `T`, PROVIDED that the entire expression being evaluated can never result in a null assignment to a ValueType. So, the null-coalescing operator `??` is just syntax sugar for the ternary operator:

```
v2 = v1 == null ? default(int) : v1.Value;
```

...which is in turn syntax sugar for an if/else:

```
if(v1==null)
   v2 = default(int);
else
   v2 = v1.Value;
```

---

Also, as of .NET 4.0, `Nullable<T>` has a "GetValueOrDefault()" method, which is a null-safe getter that basically performs the null-coalescing shown above, so this works too:

```
v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is `default(int)` really needed? What's wrong with a simple `0`?

Comment: It would work for this example, but in the general case it's recommended to use `default` where appropriate. Zero isn't always valid as a value, much less the default, so if you replace `int` with a generic `T` you'll find my code works while zero doesn't. In some future framework version, `default` may also become overloadable; if and when that happens, code using default will be easily able to take advantage, while explicit null or zero assignments will have to be changed.

Comment: This should rise to the top:  .NET 4.0, Nullable<T> has a "GetValueOrDefault()"

Comment: Thanks for coming back to edit it with GetValueOrDefault!

Comment: You may want to be careful with DateTime when you use default. This might insert the default date instead of empty.

Comment: Since .net 4 has been out for so long, It would be nice to edit this post so that GetValueOrDefault is shown as the main answer

Comment: by VS2019 suggestion v2 = v1 ?? default;

Comment: link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault

Answer (score 211):

Like this,

```
if(v1.HasValue)
   v2=v1.Value
```

Answer (score 126):

You can use the Value property for assignment.

```
v2 = v1.Value;
```

Comment: Also - if you're unsure if v1 contains null - you can use the null-coalescing operator to set a fallback value. E.g. v2 = v1 ?? 0;

Comment: And be sure to check `v1.HasValue` first.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx) says, that this will throw an exception if the `v1` is `null`. In my opinion, this is not a correct answer.

Comment: @ventiseis I would think that's desirable behavior -- I'm surprised so many of the other answers are ok with silently converting a null to 0. If you're assigning a nullable type to a non-nullable type, you should be sure that the value isn't actually null. OP didn't say "I want to assign v1 to v2, or 0 if v1 is null", but that's what everyone seemed to assume

Comment: I don't remember which version of c# got the ! operator (null forgiveness) but due to business logic i KNOW the int? is not null. I use v2 = v1!.Value to get my value.  And as @MichaelMrozek pointed out, I DO want an exception thrown, because somewhere my business got messed up. FYI I need a non null int so I can pass it to another function.

Answer (score 97):

All you need is..

```
v2= v1.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: beware that this returns 0 if it's null

Answer (score 58):

You can't do it if v1 is null, but you can check with an operator.

```
v2 = v1 ?? 0;
```

Comment: this one was best useful for me

Answer (score 54):

If you know that `v1` has a value, you can use the `Value` property:

```
v2 = v1.Value;
```

Using the `GetValueOrDefault` method will assign the value if there is one, otherwise the default for the type, or a default value that you specify:

```
v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault(); // assigns zero if v1 has no value

v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault(-1); // assigns -1 if v1 has no value
```

You can use the `HasValue` property to check if `v1` has a value:

```
if (v1.HasValue) {
  v2 = v1.Value;
}
```

There is also language support for the `GetValueOrDefault(T)` method:

```
v2 = v1 ?? -1;
```

Comment: You should not use the value without first checking to see if there is a value. Use the ?? operator instead.

Answer (score 31):

> `GetValueOrDefault()`

retrieves the value of the object. If it is null, it returns the default value of int , which is 0.

Example:

> `v2= v1.GetValueOrDefault();`

Answer (score 28):

If the default value for a given type is an acceptable result:

```
if (v1.HasValue)
    v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault();
```

If you want a different default value when the result is undefined:

```
v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault(255);    // or any valid value for int in place of 255
```

If you just want the value returned (no matter if the method failed or not):

```
v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault();
```

.NET 4.7.2.: [`GetValueOrDefault()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8b928034cfee7d43.html) returns the field value without any checking.

Answer (score 19):

As far as I'm concerned the best solution is using `GetValueOrDefault()` method.

```
v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: this one was best useful for me

Comment: beware that this returns 0 if it's null

Answer (score 19):

Depending on your usage context, you may use C# 7's pattern-matching feature:

```
int? v1 = 100;
if (v1 is int v2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"I'm not nullable anymore: {v2}");
}
```

#### EDIT:

Since some people are downvoting without leaving an explanation, I'd like to add some details to explain the rationale for including this as a viable solution.

- [C# 7's pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression) now allows us check the type of a value and cast it implicitly. In the above snippet, the if-condition will only pass when the value stored in `v1` is type-compatible to the type for `v2`, which in this case is `int`. It follows that when the value for `v1` is `null`, the if-condition will fail since null cannot be assigned to an `int`. More properly, `null` is not an `int`.
- I'd like to highlight that the that this solution may not always be the optimal choice. As I suggest, I believe this will depend on the developer's exact usage context. If you already have an `int?` and want to conditionally operate on its value *if-and-only-if* the assigned value is not null (this is the only time it is safe to convert a nullable int to a regular int without losing information), then pattern matching is perhaps one of the most concise ways to do this.

Comment: The necessity of introducing a new variable name is unfortunate, but this is the best (safest) solution if there is no default value, because there is no risk of accidentally refactoring away your `HasValue` checks.

Comment: I just don't see any advantage to this method over v1.HasValue as the check and then v1.Value to access the underlying value. I wouldn't downvote it, but I think this problem has been solved already and a new technique doesn't add much clarity to the problem. I also benchmarked it as 8-9% slower.

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking it, thats good to know! Either way you look at it, the difference is marginal at best (unless you do this in some time critical area I suppose). I look at this being more "concise" or possibly "idiomatic" since it relies on syntax sugars baked into the language instead of APIs. It's a bit subjective, but perhaps it's "more maintainable". Though truly, I like this approach more than relying on a default value as a lot of other answers suggest.

Comment: the fact that it's slower is unfortunate since this would appear to have the advantage of removing the possibility of duplicate checks, dang (edit: if it uses hard cast as the check itself, i wonder if the reason for the slowness is the underlying use of exceptions...)

Answer (score 15):

Int nullable to int conversion can be done like so:

```
v2=(int)v1;
```

Comment: If v1 is null, this will cause an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 14):

In C# 7.1 and later, type can be inferred by using the [`default` literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal) instead of the [`default` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-operator) so it can be written as below:

```
v2 = v1 ?? default;
```

Answer (score 12):

You could do

```
v2 = v1.HasValue ? v1.Value : v2;
```

Answer (score 12):

it's possible with `v2 = Convert.ToInt32(v1);`

Comment: This will work technically, but other techniques such as HasValue / Value or GetValueOrDefault run much more efficiently.

Answer (score 11):

A simple conversion between `v1` and `v2` is not possible because `v1` has a larger domain of values than `v2`.  It's everything `v1` can hold plus the `null` state.  To convert you need to explicitly state what value in `int` will be used to map the `null` state.  The simplest way to do this is the `??` operator

```
v2 = v1 ?? 0;  // maps null of v1 to 0
```

This can also be done in long form

```
int v2;
if (v1.HasValue) {
  v2 = v1.Value;
} else {
  v2 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It will assign value of `v1` to `v2` if it is not null, else it will take a default value as zero.

```
v2=v1??0
```

Or below is the other way to write it.

```
v2 = v1.HasValue?v1:0
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using any of the following conversion methods:

`v2 = Convert.ToInt32(v1);`

`v2 = (int)v1;`

`v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault();`

`v2 = v1.HasValue ? v1:0;`

Answer (score 1):

I am working on C# 9 and .NET 5, example

`foo` is nullable int, I need get int value of `foo`

```cs
var foo = (context as AccountTransfer).TransferSide;
int value2 = 0;
if (foo != null)
{
    value2 = foo.Value;
}
```

See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#examination-of-an-instance-of-a-nullable-value-type

Answer (score 0):

```
 int v2= Int32.Parse(v1.ToString());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It's better to use the "best practice" way to unwrap optionals, instead of using underhanded tricks. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types for reference

Comment: When answering a eight year old question with fifteen existing answers it is important to explain what new aspect of the question your answer is addressing, and to note if the passage of time has changed the answer. Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation.

Comment: I guess this is measurably slower than the other answers, with the detour through string. And still fails for a null

Comment: I just did a simple test: roundtrip through string it is about 60 times slower than some of the other options. A whopping 100 nanoseconds!

Answer (score -2):

Normal TypeConversion will throw an exception

Eg:

```cs
int y = 5;    
int? x = null;    
y = x.value; //It will throw "Nullable object must have a value"   
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Use `Convert.ToInt32()` method

```
int y = 5;    
int? x = null;    
y = x.Convert.ToInt32(x);    
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

This will return 0 as output because y is an integer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There is no such thing `x.Convert`, please fix the provided sample.