# ASP.NET MVC Create method null int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi my create method receives an int how can I allow this to be null-able? So I can use this method without the int sometimes.

```
   public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var model = new Job { IncidentID = id };
        ViewBag.ActionCode = new SelectList(db.ActionTypes, "ActionCode", "ActionCode");

        return View(model);
    }
```

Obviously I've tried

```
(int ? id)
```

but then here it is not happy as it cant convert int? to int here :

```
var model = new Job { IncidentID = id };
```

Comment: That gives you a compiler error, which will give you the answer if you search the web for it: use `id.Value`.

Comment: What should be assigned to `IncidentID` when `id` is not passed?

Comment: You would have to change your `IncidentID` property on `class Job` `int?` as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you are asking BUT either IncidentID will have to support null values or you will have to convert id to a non-null value before you can make that assignment.

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy nothing IncidentID will be defined by user input. @ Mike Cheel its nullable for the moment but not nullable when written to the database.

Comment: _"IncidentID will be defined by user input"_ - then why make it nullable?

Comment: Because I want to methods to create a job, one where the incident ID is received via call of create method from an incident record and also the option to create an job and define the IncidentID in the form. Should I just have a method for each option

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    var model = new Job { IncidentID = id.GetValueOrDefault(0) };
    //or var model = new Job { IncidentID = (int.parse(id) };
    ViewBag.ActionCode = new SelectList(db.ActionTypes, "ActionCode", "ActionCode");

    return View(model);
}
```

> **GetValueOrDefault(0)** helps to assigns zero if id has no value or null

or
try this

```
 var model = new Job { IncidentID = id.HasValue ? id.Value : 0 };
```

Comment: How do you know `0` should be assigned in case id was not passed?

Comment: I am going to add there is an overload for GetValueOrDefault where the default value can be specified. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have updated my answer guy's

Comment: I'll remove downvote, but that's still a guess. Maybe OP don't need new Job to be created if id was not passed

Comment: I understand you want to help OP, but OP has not provided enough information to answer his question. Your answer demonstrates [one of the ways to assign a nullable int to an int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-nullable-int-to-int), but that doesn't help OP. @Sergey's question must be answered by OP to answer this question properly, it isn't just about the assignment. Also, consider voting to close as duplicate instead of giving an answer that already exists many times.

Comment: yes i already did, and updated some another way ...

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `id` has value and assign `IncidentID` only if it has:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    var job = new Job();
    if (id.HasValue)
        job.IncidentID = id.Value;

    ViewBag.ActionCode = new SelectList(db.ActionTypes, "ActionCode", "ActionCode");
    return View(job);
}
```

Comment: I already did this sir, please see my answer

Comment: @RameshRajendran no, you don't. You are assigning `0`

Comment: Yes `id.HasValue` is false, then i assigned 0.

Comment: @RameshRajendran should I explain difference to you?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) int as your method parameter. `Nullable<T>` has a `HasValue` method which check whether a value has been assigned to the nullable variable. If it returns true, use the `Value` property to get the value of the variable.

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
  var model=new Job();
  if(id.HasValue)
  {
    model.IncidentID=id.Value;
  }
  //to do :return something
}
```

Comment: I already did this sir, please see my answer