# How do I convert int to int?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keepo getting this compile error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode'

where `SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode` is defined as `int?`

This is my code:

```
ol.FMSExpenseCode = (int)rowOrderLine.OrderLineExpenseCodeID;
```

Comment: How is it "defined as int?". Can you show us?

Comment: are you sure the `ol.FMSExpenseCode` is an int? The exception message says it is an `'SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode` type.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-nullable-int-to-int, If u mean int? ..

Comment: `FMSExpenseCode` is most probably an enum, not an int...

Comment: what is the type of OrderLineExpenseCodeID?

Comment: *"How do I convert int to int?"*... Actually you don't need to convert int to int. Check the type of `FMSExpenseCode` and `OrderLineExpenseCodeID` !!

Comment: @SteveStaple and what's the definition of `SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode`? Is it enum, class?

Answer (score 2):

'SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode' <-- is not an integer 
which means you need to convert to 'SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode' type

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the ol.FMSExpenseCode is an int? 
The exception message says it is an `SVSFinAP.Databases.FMSExpenseCode` type.

Check the type of you are working like `ol.FMSExpenseCode`,  `rowOrderLine.OrderLineExpenseCodeID` and cast to the right type. It is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to cast, assuming it's an enum?

```
ol.FMSExpenseCode = (FMSExpenseCode)rowOrderLine.OrderLineExpenseCodeID;
```

Comment: This is highly unlikely to work; there would need to be a user defined explicit operator from `int` to this type.  Odds are this will make the compiler happy and just throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: To cast from an int to an Enum? Should be fine?

Comment: How do you know its an enum?  You have a type name and nothing else.

Comment: I say "assuming it's an enum"

Comment: And what's your basis for that assumption?

Comment: People often use enums to store integral "code" types!

Answer (score -2):

```
ol.FMSExpenseCode = Convert.ToInt32(rowOrderLine.OrderLineExpenseCodeID);
```

Comment: The error is converting an `int` to a `FMSExpenseCode`, not the other way around.