# Cannot convert source type system.nullable to target type int

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I kept getting the error message below while trying to retrieve data using entity framework
and assigning to my custom class Customer

cannot convert source type 'system.nullable' to target type 'int'

CustomerNumber and Route have datatypes of Int32 and the fields in the database allows nulls

```
        select new Customer()
            {
                AccountListId = j.cost1,
                Csr = j.cost2,
                CustomerName = j.cost3,
                Address = j.cost4,
                Telephone = j.cost5,
                Contact = j.cost6,
                CustomerNumber = j.cost7,
                Branch = j.cost8,
                Route = j.cost9,
            }).ToList<Customer>();
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: And what would you like to assign to the `Int32` fields if the value from the database is `null`.  Obviously, `null` is not valid.  Do you want to set `0` or `-1`, or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert nullable int to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-nullable-int-to-int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `j.cost7` and `j.cost9` are of type `Nullable<Int32>`. I am assuming, because you haven't shown us.

Obviously, you can't assign a `Nullable<Int32>` to an `Int32` type, because, what do you do if the value is `null`?  The compiler doesn't know.  You need to decide what to do in that case, and code accordingly.

Let's say you decide to assign `-1` as a default value in case of a `null` value in the database, then you can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and do something like this:

```
    select new Customer()
        {
            AccountListId = j.cost1,
            Csr = j.cost2,
            CustomerName = j.cost3,
            Address = j.cost4,
            Telephone = j.cost5,
            Contact = j.cost6,
            CustomerNumber = j.cost7 ?? -1,
            Branch = j.cost8,
            Route = j.cost9 ?? -1,
        }).ToList<Customer>();
```

If, what you really want, is to be able to store the `null` value if there is one, then change the type of `CustomerNumber` and `Route` from `Int32` to `Nullable<Int32>`, or using an alternate syntax: `int?`.

Comment: What if I know j.cost7 is never null? Say, I've set it to nullable for purposes of validation and I know that asp net core will reject all models whose j.cost7 is null. Why doesn't the null forigiving operator work in this case? eg. CustomerNumber = j.cost7!,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default value of an int.

Eg:

```
CustomerNumber = j.cost7 ?? default(int),
        Branch = j.cost8,
        Route = j.cost9 ?? default(int),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (j.cost7 == null)
{
    CustomerNumber = 0;
}
else
{
    CustomerNumber = j.cost7
}
```

Comment: That's not gonna work, syntactically, in a with constructor.