# what is "int?" in C# types

Tags: c#, types, int

I've seen this code sample question in a exam and it works perfectly.

```
namespace Trials_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int? a = 9;
            Console.Write("{0}", a);
        }
    }
}
```

But the below code throws an error CS0266.

```
namespace Trials_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int? a = 9;
            int b = a;
            Console.Write("{0},{1}", a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain me in detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert C# nullable int to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-c-sharp-nullable-int-to-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a C# [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

> Nullable types represent value-type variables that can be assigned the value of null. You cannot create a nullable type based on a reference type. (Reference types already support the null value.)

This line `int b = a;` throws an error because you cannot directly assign an `int` type into a `nullable int` type. In other words, `int` datatype cannot accept `null` value.

Answer (score 2):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>` and indicates that a value of `null` can be assigned to the variable.

In the example given, the type of variable `b` is an `int`, which cannot accept a value of `Nullable<int>`.

Refer to [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert an int? to int, you have to cast it:

```
int? a = 9;
int b = (int)a;
```

Or:

```
int b = a.Value;
```

B.t.w: this woont give any problem:

```
int a = 9;
int? b = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Means that the variable declared with (int?) is nullable

```
int i1=1; //ok
int i2=null; //not ok

int? i3=1; //ok
int? i4=null; //ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Some info on error [`CS0266`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z8wb9e4.aspx):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>   This error occurs when your code tries to convert between two types that cannot be implicitly converted, but where an explicit conversion is available.

A nullable int (`int?`) cannot be converted simply converted to an int. An int by default cannot be null, so trying to convert something that can be null, to something that can't be null, gives you this error. Because you're trying to make this assumption, the compiler is telling you, you can't.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-c-sharp-nullable-int-to-int) post on how to convert from a nullable int to an int.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `b` is of type `int` and you are trying to assign `int?` to an `int`. which will be wrong assignment(if `a` is null, then you cannot assign it to non-nullable object `b`, so compiler will not permit this): alternatively you can use:

```
int? a = 9;
int b = a == null ? 0 : 1;
Console.Write("{0},{1}", a, b);
```