# Same variable name in different class but one is nullable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, nullable

I have the following classes which have the same variable, but one of them is nullable, the other one is not because it is a primary key in that table:

```cs
[DataServiceKey("OrderID")]
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
    // ...other properties...
    // ...

    public Employee Employees { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[DataServiceKey("EmployeeID")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    // ...other properties...
    // ...

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

The general idea between these 2 classes is an order can belong to 1 Employee, but there might also exist an order that is not assigned to any Employee yet, an Employee must have at least 1 order or more than 1. Now I am trying to create an association between `Order` class and `Employee` class, and this is how I did:

```cs
        // Create an association between Orders and Employees
        var _es = _Employees.ToDictionary(e => e.EmployeeID);
        var _os = _Orders.ToLookup(o => o.EmployeeID);
        foreach (var o in _Orders) o.Employees = _es[o.EmployeeID];
        foreach (var e in _Employees) e.Orders = _os[e.EmployeeID];
```

I got `cannot convert from "int?" to "int"` error in `_es[o.EmployeeID]`, I have tried every solutions provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-c-sharp-nullable-int-to-int), but none of them are work for me...I have also tried to use `_es[o.EmployeeID.Value]`, it does solve the error but this time it gaves me `System.InvalidOperationException` error when I run it. Is there any possible solution will be applied to my issue ?

Comment: you can try like this  `foreach (var o in _Orders) o.Employees = _es[o.EmployeeID] ?? Default(int);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an `int?` for a key to a dictionary where `int` is needed.

`o.Employee` is an `int?`.

`es` is a `Dictionary<int, Employee>`.

You probably want:

```
o.Employees = o.EmployeeID != null ? _es[o.EmployeeID] : null;
```

Comment: Instead of checking `null`, check whether it has value using `HasValue`

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu checking for `null` is the way most idiomatic to C#. It is syntax sugar for `HasValue` -- the two are identical.

Comment: Yes, I agree.. but `Nullable` variable contains predefined property to check whether the variable has value or null.

Answer (score 1):

Check `HasValue` before assign the value.

```
foreach (var o in _Orders)
{
    if (_es[o.EmployeeID].HasValue)
    {
        o.Employees = _es[o.EmployeeID];
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach (var o in _Orders) o.Employees = _es[o.EmployeeID].HasValue ? _es[o.EmployeeID] : null;
```