# cannot convert from 'float?' to 'float

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public float? InputCutOffFrequency { get; set; }//fc

public float? InputF1 { get; set; }

public float? InputF2 { get; set; }

public float InputTransitionBand { get; set; }

public float InputFS { get; set; }

public float calcFc1(float f, float fs, float transition)
{
    float _f = f + (transition / 2);
    _f /= fs;
    return _f;
}

float fc1;
fc1 = calcFc1(InputCutOffFrequency, InputFS, InputTransitionBand);
```

When running this code, I get this error:

```
cannot convert from 'float?' to 'float
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What do you want the value to be if it’s null?

Comment: i want it to be equals 0

Comment: you either supply default value like `InputCutOffFrequency??0` or ignore it via `InputCutOffFrequency.Value`

Comment: @IłyaBursov - Value will throw if its null, it doesnt 'ignore it'

Comment: @pm100 I meant ignore possibility of NRE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert C# nullable int to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995317/how-to-convert-c-sharp-nullable-int-to-int)

Comment: `public float? InputF2 { get; set; }` to `public float InputF2 { get; set; } = 0.0f;` I prefer to initialize it to avoid nullable warnings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a nullable float so you will need to specify you want the value.

```
fc1 = calcFc1(InputCutOffFrequency.Value, InputFS, InputTransitionBand);
```

Or you can default it if it's null

```
fc1 = calcFc1(InputCutOffFrequency.GetValueOrDefault(0), InputFS, InputTransitionBand);
```

Comment: Good use of the `GetValueOrDefault` method. I always forget this exists

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the `?`, when used after a type, indicates that the variable associated with the type can be null or a concrete value. The function you wrote, `calcFcl`, has a signature that takes three floats and produces a float as output. However, when you call it, you're providing it with a `float?` as the first argument. Since floating-point operations with null values aren't valid, the compiler doesn't know what to do when this is the case.

There are three ways you can address this issue:

1. Change `InputCutOffFrequency` so that it is of type `float` instead of type `float?`.
2. Change how you call `calcFc1` so that you send the value of `InputCutOffFrequency` instead of the nullable value:

```
// Force a value (this will throw an InvalidOperationException if `InputCutOffFrequency is null)
fc1 = calcFc1(InputCutOffFrequency.Value, InputFS, InputTransitionBand);

// Coalesce the value (this will force a value, but you need to be sure it's the one you want)
fcl = calcFcl(InputCutOffFrequency ?? 0, InputFS, InputTransitionBand);
```

3. Change the signature of `calcFcl` so that it accepts, for its first argument, a value of `float?` and then modify the function body so that it handles the case where the first argument is null.

```
public float calcFc1(float? f, float fs, float transition)
{
    float _f = (f ?? 0) + (transition / 2);
    _f /= fs;
    return _f;
}
```

In this case, the `f ?? 0` is coalescing `f` to a value. Essentially, if `f` is null, then 0 will be used. If `f` is not null, then the value in `f` will be used.

For more information on nullable types in C#, feel free to check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types).

Answer (score 1):

1 :

```
fc1 = calcFc1(InputCutOffFrequency.Value, InputFS, InputTransitionBand);
```

or 2 :

```
public float calcFc1(float f?, float fs, float transition)
{
    float _f = f + (transition / 2);
    _f /= fs;
    return _f;
}
```

You can change signature of nullable variable as `float?` in your function. **[2]**

Another way is getting `Value` of nullable variable like `InputCutOffFrequency.Value` **[1]**